# www.google.com refused to connect

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

i to problema code in the google maps to js and don't appear in website, in erorr code chromewebdata/:1 Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
and my code

```
import React from "react";

const GoogleMap = ({ extraClass }) => {
  return (
    <div className={`google-map__${extraClass}`}>
      <iframe
        title="Nusa Putra University Google Map"
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Nusa+Putra+University/@-6.9172783,106.8341234,14z/data=!4m20!1m13!4m12!1m4!2m2!1d106.8296372!2d-6.9262137!4e1!1m6!1m2!1s0x2e6836505836821d:0x619b6e8271f232cc!2snusaputra!2m2!1d106.8736239!2d-6.9053905!3m5!1s0x2e6836505836821d:0x619b6e8271f232cc!8m2!3d-6.9053905!4d106.8736239!16s%2Fg%2F1pzthfrxz?entry=ttu"
        className={`map__${extraClass}`}
        allowFullScreen
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GoogleMap;
```

help me error appear to website

Comment: Go to Google Maps, click your point of interest, click "share", select "embedded map" and copy the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

The Google server is [sending a header that tells your browser you can't view that page in an iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), which is exactly what you're trying to do.

There is no way to sidestep this security feature.

If you want to embed a Google map on your site, you can use the aptly named [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started).